# How to get the doctrine setter getter name dynamically by entity member

Tags: php, doctrine

in Doctorine format

if entity name is `$name` setter name is `getName()`, if the name is `$myTel` setter name is `getMyTel`

Now I have only entity names like `name` and `myTel`

then I want to get getter setter name.

How can I do that??

```
$hash = array("name" => 'yard' ,"myTel" => '09203');
foreach ($hash as key => $value){
  $myEntity->get{Name or MyTel}($value); // want to get this setter name dynamically.
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this inside of your loop:

```
$method = "get" . ucfirst($key);
$myEntity->$method($value);
```

Remember to be careful when you are using variables to call methods.

By the way, why are you calling `get` to a setter method? Shouldn't be `setName` and `setMyTel`? ;)

Comment: Thank you very much. and set/get is simply my mistake. I use 'get' for getter and 'set' for setter

Comment: @whitebear You are welcome :) Remeber to vote if it was helpful :D